# ASP.MVC: Separation of concerns and custom attribute class w/ authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, separation-of-concerns, actionfilterattribute

I'm working on separating concerns in MVC. Currently everything is mixed up (Library functions, extensions, custom filter attributes, data access level), but I want to have 2 separate projects for those (MySolution.Lib and MySolution.DBModel). I want to separate my custom filter attribute to Lib project. DBModel is already referencing Lib, so I've done everything beside this one. What's the best way to implement this? Is it possible to pass to the attribute values in another custom property and work only on text inside Attribute implementation. So that the Attribute would be used something like this:

```
[AuthorizeUser(AccessLevel = "Admin", UserRights = DBModel.User.GetUserRights(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)]
public ActionResult MyAction()
```

Here's the current implementation

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    // Custom property
    public string AccessLevel { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        List<string> accessLevels = AccessLevel.Split(new[] {','}).ToList();

        //this is taken from DB by GetUserRights() method from MySecurity static class
        var privilegeLevels = MySecurity.GetUserRights(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);


        return accessLevels.Any(privilegeLevels.Contains)
               || privilegeLevels.Contains("Admin") || privilegeLevels.Contains("Super User");
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var helper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(helper.Action("Index", "Unauthorized"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using ASP.NET Identity http://www.asp.net/identity instead of trying to implement your own role system? It is designed for this and fairly flexible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it at all. Is this possible to combine it with LDAP auth (Intranet app) using Forms Authentication in MVC?

Comment: Regardless, this is the wrong place to be doing your authorization.  Attributes should not be doing database access themselves, or calling services like that.  It adds dependencies in the wrong places.  What you should be doing is overriding Application_AuthorizeRequest and then creating a custom GenericPrinciple with the roles you need, then using the standard Authorize attribute unchanged.